# Renaming, Moving, and Deleting Original Directory

Tags: python-3.x, shutil, os.walk

I'm trying to right a script that will walk through a given directory and rename, move, and delete the original directory. Each directory has a `*.mp4` file and a subfolder containing `*.jpg` files. I'm having trouble deleting the original directory when I'm done renaming and moving the files. What so far is:

```
import datetime, os, re, shutil, logging, smtplib

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO, format = ' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
#logging.disable(logging.info)

path = '\\\\RT-N66U\\sda2\\Documents'
desired_text1 = re.compile(r'^\d{3}_[a-zA-Z]+\d{3}.jpg')
desired_text2 = re.compile(r'^\d{3}_[a-zA-Z]+_\d{3}.jpg')
renamed_files = ''

for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
    if folderName.startswith(path + '\\GEO-'):
            logging.info('The current folder is ' + folderName)

            for subfolder in subfolders:
                    if subfolder.startswith('Pics'):
                            pic_folder = subfolder

            for filename in filenames:                        
                    if filename.endswith('.mp4'):
                            changed_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(filename[3:17], '%b %d, %Y').strftime('%y.%m.%d') # Changes the name of the date to the desired format
                            year = datetime.datetime.strptime(filename[3:17], '%b %d, %Y').strftime('%Y')
                            name = filename[20:-25]
                            name = name.lower()
                            modified_name = '.'.join(re.findall('\S+', name))
                            final_name = 'geo.' + changed_date + '.' + modified_name

                    if not os.path.exists('\\\\RT-N66U\\sda2\\Me\\GEO\\%s\\%s\\%s' % (year, changed_date[3:5], final_name)):            
                            os.makedirs('\\\\RT-N66U\\sda2\\Me\\GEO\\%s\\%s\\%s' % (year, changed_date[3:5], final_name)) 

                    if not os.path.exists('\\\\RT-N66U\\sda2\\Me\\GEO\\%s\\%s\\%s\\%s' % (year, changed_date[3:5], final_name, pic_folder)):
                            os.makedirs('\\\\RT-N66U\\sda2\\Me\\GEO\\%s\\%s\\%s\\%s' % (year, changed_date[3:5], final_name, pic_folder))        

                    if filename.endswith('.mp4'):
                            logging.info(filename)
                            os.rename(folderName + '\\' + filename, '\\\\RT-N66U\\sda2\\Me\\GEO\\%s\\%s\\%s\\%s.mp4' % (year, changed_date[3:5], final_name, final_name))

                    # This part will logg and rename the files by adding a '_'
                    mo1 = desired_text1.search(filename)
                    mo2 = desired_text2.search(filename)

                    if mo1:
                            logging.info(folderName + '\\' + filename)
                            os.rename(folderName + '\\' + filename, '\\\\RT-N66U\\sda2\\Me\\GEO\\%s\\%s\\%s\\%s\\%s_%s' % (year, changed_date[3:5], final_name, pic_folder, filename[:-7], filename[-7:]))
                            renamed_files += filename + ' -> ' + filename[:-7] + '_' + filename[-7:] + '\n'

                    elif mo2:
                            logging.info(folderName + '\\' + filename)
                            os.rename(folderName + '\\' + filename, '\\\\RT-N66U\\sda2\\Me\\GEO\\%s\\%s\\%s\\%s\\%s' % (year, changed_date[3:5], final_name, pic_folder, filename))
                            renamed_files += filename + '\n'  

    # This part will check if the directory is empty and delete it if so
    if os.listdir(folderName) == []:
            logging.info(folderName)
            shutil.rmtree(folderName)
```

What ends up happening is that all sub-directories will be deleted if they're empty and leaving the primary directory empty. I would like the primary directory to be removed as well, since all the files have been moved. Is there a way to accomplish this within the `for` statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean deleting the directory known as folderName inside your main `for` loop, I think it's not really possible since you're iterating over an object that contains it. Like if inside a `for i in this_list:` you would like to remove an object from this_list. This is not possible before you're out of the loop.

In order to achieve what you want, I would write a function to recurse into the folder tree. The idea would be something like:

```
def process_folder(folder_name):
    do some stuff on files
    get the subfolders of folder_name
    for f in subfolders:
        process_folder(subfolder_name)
        if subfolder_name is empty, delete it
    maybe do some other stuff on files
```

and in the main script, call `process_folder(path)`. (This would leave only the top folder there even if it's empty though, so be sure you don't want to delete it; or to call process_folder at a higher level, or to add an instruction to delete it too if it's empty).